# How to use MapProxy to fill missing samples

Tags: mapproxy

I want to use Mapproxy [`resampling_method`](https://mapproxy.org/docs/1.11.0/configuration.html#image-format-options) to fill missing samples when scaling. I don't know how to do that or if this is even possible?

I use [AWS terrain tiles](https://registry.opendata.aws/terrain-tiles/) as data source:

```
sources:
  aws_elevation_tiles_source:
    type: tile
    grid: GLOBAL_WEBMERCATOR
    url: https://s3.amazonaws.com/elevation-tiles-prod/terrarium/%(z)s/%(x)s/%(y)s.png
```

Another (custom written) tile server `myserver` calculates a feature for each of this 256x256 tiles, which can be represented as a single pixel. The tile coordinates are corresponding.

```
layers:
  - name: my_layer
    title: My Feature
    sources: [my_cache]

caches:
  my_cache:
    sources: [my_source]
    grids: [my_grid]
    image:
      resampling_method: bicubic

sources:
  my_source:
    type: tile
    grid: my_grid
    url: http://myserver/tms/1.0.0/feature/EPSG3857/%(z)s/%(x)s/%(y)s.png
    transparent: true
    image:
      format: image/png

grids:
    my_grid:
        base: GLOBAL_WEBMERCATOR
        tile_size: [256, 256]
```

## Approach A

Each tile is a 1x1 PNG. The calculated feature is at the center of each tile.

[image]

## Approach B

Each tile is a 256x256 transparent PNG with an intransparent pixel at (127,127). The calculated feature is at the center of each tile.

[image: 1x1 PNG]

Changing or removing the `resampling_method` option doesn't has any effect
(even if approach A looks like nearest neighborhood resampling).

I also tried to use grayscale samples, with the same effect.

What I want to have is a WMS server which shows the calculated features on a map and uses bicubic interpolation to fill the space between the samples.